# Javascript Slide Show Random Sequence

Tags: javascript, image, random, sequence, slideshow

I am trying to fit in "Math.random" function in the following code so that the images are displayed in a random order but I am not successful. Unaltered slideshow code is as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {

height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

 /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
<a href="https://www.one.com" target="_blank">
<img src="1.jpg" style="border-radius:3px;">
</a>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<a href="https://www.two.com" target="_blank">
<img src="2.jpg" style="border-radius:3px;">
</a>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<a href="https://www.three.com" target="_blank">
<img src="3.jpg" style="border-radius:3px;">
</a>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot"></span> 
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
setTimeout(showSlides, 1500); 
}
</script>
```

How can I use Math.random function with this loop for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) to display in random sequence. Thanks

Comment: Some combinations like: (i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length); i++)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of slide id's and shuffle the array. Then loop through the array. Each slide will display only once but in a random order.

```
function shuffleArray(arr) {
    arr.sort(() => (Math.random() - 0.5)
}

let ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
shuffleArray(ids)

for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
   let s = ids[i]
   slides[s].style.display = "block"   //etc
}
```